# How can i send image with text with share

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

Currently i am using the below code for sharing text:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");

    i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is tesing");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
```

From this i can able to share text on any social media platform.

But i want to also share the image with this and my image is in binary form.

```
InputStream input = new java.net.URL(
                                product.getString("url")).openStream();

 // Decode Bitmap
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
```

So image sharing i have written below code:

```
i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bitmap);
```

But it is not working. It shares the text like :- `android.graphics.Bitmap@43394c40`

So how can i share image also with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu have to save the bitmap from url into the disk first then use the file to be passed on intent.

```
    File file = writebitmaptofilefirst("the_new_image","http://www.theimagesource.com/blahblahblah.jpg");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Add this method

```
public static File writebitmaptofilefirst(String filename, String source) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File mFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/temp_images");
    if (!mFolder.exists()) {
        mFolder.mkdir();
    }
    OutputStream outStream = null;


    File file = new File(mFolder.getAbsolutePath(), filename + ".png");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        file = new File(extStorageDirectory, filename + ".png");
        Log.e("file exist", "" + file + ",Bitmap= " + filename);
    }
    try {
        URL url = new URL(source);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.e("file", "" + file);
    return file;

}
```

Comment: Downloading image is failed.

Comment: Ok solved it. The error was "network on main thread" i have put that whole code into async task.

Answer (score 5):

1. First of all, you have to download that image and save in ExternalStorage. [Check this link](http://velmuruganandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2013/07/download-image-from-url-to-sd-card-in.html)
2. Social apps don't support sharing images and text together.
3. Use this sample code below:

   ```
    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("image/*");
    i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is tesing");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile("file_path"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share via"));
   ```

**Supporting APP:**

1. Google+
2. Hangout
3. Gmail
4. Email
5. Whatsapp

**Not Supporting APP:**

1. Facebook
2. Skype
3. Hike

Comment: Could you write English, please?

Comment: @xenteros which is current language?

Comment: @NiranjPatel only image is sharing. Message box is empty. Using above code. You already mentioned that its not supported. Is there anyway to make it supportable.

Comment: Right answer sharing images and text not supported in some apps

Comment: do you have any link that shows supporting and not supporting apps?

Answer (score 1):

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse( "file://"+filelocation));
```

Programming Android devices, avoid using bitmaps for Earth. When you load bitmap to your memory, you use your RAM which is critical resource on small devices. Use **Uri**s as often as possible.

**EDIT:**

You can send an image and text together e.g. via e-mail. Your idea to put everything into an Intent is correct. The only mistake is working on bitmap instead of working on a bitstream. Before sending a picture, you have to save it first in device's storage. If you don't save it first, you will achieve buffer overflow sooner than you expect.

Comment: But this image is come from URL and it saves in bitmap.

Comment: you have to save this file first. You can later remove it just after you send it via email, however the good practice is not to delete it. User will delete it on his own if he needs to delete it.

Comment: I want to know do I have to create another Intent to send Image or I can send within the same intent with which we are sending text??

Comment: It's the same intent. You put all the data in one Intent Action.SEND. The key is to put bitstream of an image instead of bitmap. Your solution might work by luck if the device has huge RAM.